# Sort a list with np.arrays python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sort a list with four numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np 
import datetime

time_origin=[]

filelist=['3.csv','2.csv','1.csv','4.csv'] 

for i in np.arange(4):
    time_origin.append(np.loadtxt(
        filelist[i],delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols=(0,),unpack=True)) 

time_origin.sort()
```

However, it doesn't work.

The expected result:

for example:

```
a=[array[1,2,3,4],array[6,2],array[0,12,1,4,5]]
```

I want to sort a based on the length of each array

the expected result is:

```
a=[array[6,2],array[1,2,3,4],array[0,12,1,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

sort using  `len` as the sort key:

```
 time_origin.sort(key=len)
```

Python sorts lists element by element, if all elements are the same the longer list will get sorted after but `[1,2,3]` will get sorted before `[12]` because `12 > 1`.

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, a more relevant answer than my one.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the built-in `sorted` function as such:

```
arrays = [np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = sorted(arrays, key=lambda x:len(x))
```

The core idea here is to use the lambda function.